# How to echo jquery/javascript div with multple classes in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can only seem to add a single class the 2nd class will always be placed outside quotation marks no matter what i do:

```
  <?php
echo "$('.postcode').append( '<div class= " . 'errorpostcode' . " ".'test'.">Postcode- huisnummercombinatie niet gevonden</div>' );";

?>
```

Value gets placed outside quotation marks

[image]

Comment: Why are you not just outputting that `div` with PHP? Also, you can just change the class bit to: `class= \"errorpostcode test\"`. The issue is that your quotation marks do not match up.

Comment: Please do not swear in your questions. There is absolutely no need for it

Comment: Ok that worked, sometimes of you have been staring at code for hours you just don't see the obvious solutions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below:

```
<?php echo "$('.postcode').append( '<div class= \"" . 'errorpostcode' . " ".'test'."\">Postcode- huisnummercombinatie niet gevonden</div>' );"; ?>
```

The issue with your code is you are not adding quotes, you need to add quote and escape it like '**\"**' to make it visible.

Comment: Select code and do ctrl + k or click on `{}` button

Answer (score 0):

Generating and injecting javascript that will inject HTML into your page seems a little overcomplicated, you might want to rethink what you are doing.

That said, i think *this* is what you are after

```
print("\$('.postcode').append(\"<div class='".$errorpostcode." ".$test."'>Postcode- huisnummercombinatie niet gevonden</div>\");");
```

Answer (score 0):

The html your php generates is the following:

```
<div class= errorpostcode test >
```

This is obviously bad html, but the browser tries to make sense of it, and deducts that the first part is a class, but it has no idea what the second part is.

So add quotes to your php, to end up with something like this:

```
<?php
echo "$('.postcode').append( '<div class=' " . 'errorpostcode' . " ".'test'."'>Postcode- huisnummercombinatie niet gevonden</div>' );";
?>
```

`"` and `'` do the same job, but I've added `'` so that it doesn't conflict with the `"` of the `echo`.

Add it just after the `class=` and just before the `>`

Your generated html then becomes:

```
<div class="errorpostcode test">
```